# Sparsity of the inverse of a non-negative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, algebraic-graph-theory, sparsity

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{b \times b}$ be a matrix with non-negative entries. Suppose that $A$ is invertible. Further suppose that all the diagonal entries of $A$ are non-null. My claim is the following: 
$$\text{bin}(A^{-1})=\text{bin}(A^{b-1})\,,$$
where $\text{bin}: \mathbb{R}^{b \times b}\rightarrow \{0,1\}^{b \times b}$ gives the binary sparsity pattern of $A$, in the sense that an entry of matrix $\text{bin}(A)$ is $1$ if and only if the corresponding entry of $A$ is different from $0$. For instance
$$\text{bin}\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0\\0&2&1\\1&0&2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\right)=\text{bin}\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0\\0&2&1\\1&0&2\end{bmatrix}^2\right)=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\,.$$

Notice that, by Cayley-Hamilton's theorem and the fact that the diagonal of $A$ is full, I expect any counter-example to my claim to be such that one entry of $\text{bin}(A^{-1})$ is $0$ while the same entry of $\text{bin}(A^{b-1})$ is $1$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that there is an entry of $bin(A^{-1})$ which is $0$ while the same entry of $bin(A^{a-1})$ is $1$.

Comment: More concisely, you conjecture that if $A \in \mathbb{R}^{a \times a}_{\geq 0}$ is invertible, $A^{-1}$ has the same sparsity pattern as $A^{a-1}$. Moreover, you are asking if someone can find a counterexample in which $(A^{-1})_{ij} = 0$ and $(A^{a-1})_{ij} \neq 0$ for some $(i, j)$.

Comment: Do you want $\mbox{bin}(A^{-1})$ to be equal to, less than or equal to, or greater than or equal to $\mbox{bin}(A^{b-1})$?  You've described in this in different and inconsistent ways.

Comment: @parsiad I additionally ask that $A$ has a full diagonal, so that the sparsity of $A$ "grows" with the powers of $A$. The counter-example I'm asking for is just a counter-example of the claim.

at Rodrigo agreed. Changed it to $b \times b$

Comment: @Brian As written, I want it to be equal. The counter-example I'm asking for is just a counter-example of the fact that they are equal. Since the diagonal of $A$ is full, it is impossible that $\text{bin}(A)^{-1}$ is "fuller" than $A^{b-1}$ by Cayley-Hamilton.

Comment: So you'd be happy with any example where corresponding entries in $\mbox{bin}(A^{-1})$ and $\mbox{bin}(A^{b-1})$ are different, right?  That's not what you wrote in the last line of your question.

Comment: @Brian Yes. I expect any counter-example to be such that $\text{bin}({A^{-1}})<\text{bin}({A}^{b-1})$ because of cayley Hamilton and full diagonal. But maybe I'm wrong :) I'll edit the question to make it clearer

Comment: That's helpful context- I'd suggest adding it to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1\cr 1 & 2 & 2\cr 1 & 2 & 3}^{-1} = \pmatrix{2 & -1 & 0\cr 
-1 & 2 & -1\cr 0 & -1 & 1\cr}$$

Comment: great, thanks a lot!

Comment: @pulosky you can accept an answer to mark your question as answered